# What could cause numpy.nanstd() to return nan?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a relatively large 1-D array (20000 observations). When I calculate descrpitive statistics such as  standard deviation, mean, sum, I get nan value, but when I calculate a percintle from the same array I get the value I expected. I tried functions such as numpy.nanstd, nanmean. What could I be doing wrong? I am using python 2.7.9

Comment: This probably means that your large 1D array has some 'nan' values in it. numpy.nanmean(array) should work if mean(array) outputs nan.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I tried numpy.nanmean(array) too, but I still get nan values. I thought functions such as numpy.nanmean() and numpy.nanstd() would take care of nan values automatically.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong in my array. There was '-inf'  value. Everything is working properly after after masking '-inf'  value. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

There are three circumstances where [`np.nanstd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html) might return *NaN*:

1. If the input is empty
2. If all of the elements in the input are *NaN*
3. If one of the elements is either positive or negative infinity. To understand why this happens, remember that the formula for standard deviation is

   [image]

   Since *x* contains *inf*, the mean of *x* will also be *inf*. Therefore when computing the deviations from the mean, there is at least one element that is equal to *inf - inf*. If you try this at the IPython prompt, you will see that *inf - inf* is defined as *NaN*.

In the former two cases you should get a helpful warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible explanation for *inf* output from *np.nanstd* is related what *Numpy* data type is used to store data. See the example below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1239., 1485.,   63.,  393.,   37., 1186.,   13.,  402.,  404., 915.], dtype='float16')
print(np.nanstd(a)) # returns inf

a = a.astype('float32')
print(np.nanstd(a)) # returns 519.87177
```

Comment: Ah, the reason that happens is because `(x - x.mean()) ** 2` overflows the `float16` type for some elements in the array. This results in a _inf - inf_, like in case 3 in my answer. You should see `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply` if this happens.