# nanstd in numpy doesn't ingore nan

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

According to the description of the nanstd and nanmean, and other nan functions in numpy, the nan shall be ignored. However, I got nan as a result of computing standard deviation and mean with nan functions.

Below, I compute the mean and std of a whole array and it's subset. The nan values are at the very end hence are not included if I do the calculations on the subset of it.

```
>>> nanstd(arr[1,:1000])
0.83957712570078991
>>> nanstd(arr[1,:])
nan
>>> std(arr[1,:])
nan
numpy.__version__
'1.12.0'
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954429/what-could-cause-numpy-nanstd-to-return-nan), there are few reasons why nanstd might return nan.
Here are

1. If the input is empty  **(Not the case)**
2. If all of the elements in the input are NaN **(Not the case)**
3. one of the elements is either positive or negative infinity. **(There is an inf value in my array)**

---

## Solved

[The solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954429/what-could-cause-numpy-nanstd-to-return-nan)

Comment: While editing my question I have found the solution.

Comment: You should answer your own question if you have found its solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could cause numpy.nanstd() to return nan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954429/what-could-cause-numpy-nanstd-to-return-nan)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned as an answer to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954429/what-could-cause-numpy-nanstd-to-return-nan) , there are few reasons why nanstd might return nan.
Here are

1. If the input is empty  **(Not the case)**
2. If all of the elements in the input are NaN **(Not the case)**
3. one of the elements is either positive or negative infinity. **(There is an inf value in my array)**

Going through the list I found out that I do have inf value in my array